# convert time from database

Tags: php

I have a value in the database defined as mediumint(11).  Currently it returns 3600 if I run a query.

This function here should convert that value to: 1 hr.  But it doesn't when I run the function.  I get no value.

```
function strTime($s) {
  $d = intval($s/86400);
  $s -= $d*86400;

  $h = intval($s/3600);
  $s -= $h*3600;

  $m = intval($s/60);
  $s -= $m*60;

  if ($d) $str = $d . 'd ';
  if ($h) $str .= $h . 'h ';
  if ($m) $str .= $m . 'm ';
  if ($s) $str .= $s . 's';

  return $str;
 }
```

Pretty basic, must be something with the value in the db?

Code that calls this (Joomla specific):

```
$query = "SELECT streaming_limit FROM #__cc_users WHERE user_id=".$user->id;
$db->setQuery($query);
$steaming_limit = $db->loadResult(); //returns 3600
echo strTime($streaming_limit); //returns nothing
```

Comment: I have a feeling there's a question in there somewhere, but where's the *problem*?

Comment: So what's the question exactly? What's your current output? In other words: at what point can we help you? ;-)

Comment: Whoops, added the edit.  Basically this function doesn't return 1 hr as I expect instead I get an empty value.

Comment: It seems to work? http://codepad.org/XOqhtfAg However you're passing your value to it must be the problem.

Comment: Why don't you calculate the seconds first, then the minutes... ie, `$secs = $s % 60; $s /= 60; $mins = $s % 60; $s /= 60;` etc?

Comment: I don't think it is the function.  As @Jared says it must be the value passed to it.  That's why I provided the database value (mediumint).  Which I think has to be the issue...

Comment: So why didn't you post the query and code that calls it as well?

Comment: if you are in PHP why don't you use [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and the [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function?  Besides this specific case they will make your thing way more robust for the future and any other date formats you might want to eventually use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more robust way to do this is PHP's [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes, which exist specifically for this sort of thing.
The code below creates two DateTime objects, adds the specified number of seconds
to one object and then calculates the interval between the two.

At that point you can format the time difference however you'd like using [`DateInterval::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

```
function strTimeDiff($seconds)
{
  $date1 = new DateTime();
  $date2 = new DateTime();
  $date2->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$seconds.'S'));
  $interval = $date1->diff($date2);

  echo $interval->format('%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
}

$secs_from_db = 3600;
echo strTimeDiff($secs_from_db);
// 0 days, 1 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like this:

"converts number of seconds to an array containing hours, minutes and seconds separately"

From http://codeaid.net/php/convert-seconds-to-hours-minutes-and-seconds-%28php%29

```
<?php

/**
 * Convert number of seconds into hours, minutes and seconds
 * and return an array containing those values
 *
 * @param integer $seconds Number of seconds to parse
 * @return array
 */
function secondsToTime($seconds)
{
    // extract hours
    $hours = floor($seconds / (60 * 60));

    // extract minutes
    $divisor_for_minutes = $seconds % (60 * 60);
    $minutes = floor($divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    // extract the remaining seconds
    $divisor_for_seconds = $divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    $seconds = ceil($divisor_for_seconds);

    // return the final array
    $obj = array(
        "h" => (int) $hours,
        "m" => (int) $minutes,
        "s" => (int) $seconds,
    );
    return $obj;
}
```

Comment: This has the exact same problem...so this won't work as a solution.